# Keep td "expanded" even if empty

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

**Situation**

The situation is, in the program I am working on I have a 2 *10 table with every `<td>` Representing an area on the paper where I will print an item.

**Problem**

The problem is, Only one cell will have information at a time, and in such an event the entire table "collapses"and doesnt respect the table cell format.

**What I have done**

I believe I have tried every possible option I could try,

```
&nbsp,empty-cells:show, table-layout: fixed;
```

none of these options help me, when the table is empty is "closes"
My last option was to put a blank placeholder image in all cells.
HOWEVER that failed because when I add my specific details to the code it goes "below" the blank image effectively throwing off my table

this is part of the table code

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="labelData">
    <tr>
        <td class="blankl">
            <div id="content">

                <img src="~/Content/Image/blankimg.png" alt="Image" />

            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="blankl" style="width:303px; height:5px">
            <div id="content">

                <img src="~/Content/Image/blankimg.png" alt="Image" />

            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Script where clicking on a cell adds the data in the "active class"

```
 var content = $('#content');
            $('td').click(function () {
                $('td').removeClass('active');
                $('td').removeClass('blankl');

                $(this).append(content).addClass('active');
```

Edit 
Fiddle added but strangely it works in it.

https://jsfiddle.net/kemcoder/95jdr5pp/

I should also add that the table issue occurs when I try to print.

```
function printData() {


    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("labelData");
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();

}
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle

Comment: I'd like to see your css and js, I suspect we'll find the problem there. As @Pamblam suggested: Please make a jsfiddle

Comment: @mmgross added a fiddle

Comment: So, you just completed the first step in debugging your code: You removed a portion of it (to make a fiddle) and now the error is gone. Next step: Look at at the code you removed, your error is probably there.

Comment: @mmgross not exactly, as we cant call print in the fiddle enviroment

Comment: Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95jdr5pp/3/) ... does that one work in your environment ? ... let me know and I post it as an answer

Comment: @LGSon Problem with that fiddle in the real enviroment is, when you click the first row the new image is appended BELOW the blank one. casing it to stretch

Comment: Maybe if you show that script's basics we could help avoid _adding_ and do a replace, which seems sound to do in this case

Answer (score 0):

Can you give every cell a fixed height and a percentage width?

```
#labelData td {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
}
```